# Teradata LIKE operator without wildcard?

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

In Oracle, the LIKE operator can be used either with or without a wildcard.
For example "where name like 'SMITH'" will return rows where the name column is exactly 'SMITH',
and "where name like 'SMITH%'" will return rows where the name column begins with 'SMITH' followed by 0 or more other characters.

However in Teradata, "where name like 'SMITH'" returns nothing.  Does ANSI standard not specify behavior for the LIKE operator if used without a wildcard?

Boolean algebra says 'SMITH' like 'SMITH' is true.  Oracle behaves this way; Teradata does not. Can Teradata SQL be tweaked to enable the LIKE operator to work both with and without wildcards?

Comment: "Can Teradata SQL be tweaked to enable the LIKE operator to work both with and without wildcards?" - Yeah: add a wildcard if not present.

Comment: When did Boolean algebra say that?  I must have missed that talk.  Was it at TED?

Answer (score 4):

This is what i get on each and every Teradata release:

```
 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
SELECT
   CASE WHEN 'smith' LIKE 'smith'  THEN 'equal' ELSE 'not equal' END,
   CASE WHEN 'smith' LIKE 'smith ' THEN 'equal' ELSE 'not equal' END,
   CASE WHEN 'smith' =    'smith ' THEN 'equal' ELSE 'not equal' END;


 *** QUERY completed. One ROW FOUND. 3 COLUMNS returned.
 *** Total elapsed TIME was 1 SECOND.

<CASE  expression>  <CASE  expression>  <CASE  expression>
------------------  ------------------  ------------------
equal               not equal           equal
```

And this is definitely 100% Standard SQL compliant.

What you probably did is comparing a CHAR column or a VARCHAR column with some trailing blanks in it. Oracle silently pads the shorter string with blanks before comparing (which is wrong according to Standard SQL) similar to a comparison using equality (=).